# How can I update my firebase realtime database every hour?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, service

I want to update my firebase realtime database every hour. I can't use background services as they are banned in Android O. I can't use job scheduler and work manager as they are not suitable for Timebase application.

I already tried the alarm manager but it is not firing at write time due to doze mode.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't bypass doze mode.

Comment: You really need to do that on Android side? You could do easier with Cloud Functions

Comment: @Mahdi-Malv  is there any way that fmc can help me this problem

Comment: @Shermano can you elaborate what are you saying

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `scheduled cloud function` which will run at the time you specified.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions

Answer (score 0):

```
export scheduleUpdate =
functions.pubsub.schedule('every 60 minutes').onRun((context) => {
    console.log('This will run every 60 minutes!');
    // update logic code here
})
```